What exactly do you do when optimising objective functions? Are you supposed to use a computer to calculate it?
Using math for interior decorating with lamps
^I was looking at the answer to this question and I barely understood the equation being written out. However at the end, it just says "Finally maximise blah blah blah. End"
There was no working out following that. How are you supposed to exactly maximise something? Are you supposed to input it into a computer and have it do it for you?
If there is working out, could somebody explain it to me (laymans terms please, I'm not in uni yet)
This is a screenshot of the part I am confused about

Some optimization problems can be done algebraically with pen and paper (and perhaps some calculus), others can use a computer. There's no one-size-fits-all answer.

If you were going to use a computer to solve it, how would you start about it?

I have no idea, I thought there would be some program to do it for me after you put in the functions??

Maximizing and other optimization problems are a major part of applied mathematics. Techniques are extensively studied for a variety of problems. Some are exact and others use approximations. Even when using a computer to solve the problem you often need additional information about the problem to choose between methods.

Different solvers can do different things. In short, read the documentation.

sorry for the late reply but thanks yall this helped alot. I'll probably ask a separate question once I've figured out the function I need to optimize.
